# How to include variable in a path?

Tags: shell, powershell, path

I am trying to create a file called creation_DDMMYYYY where DDMMYYYY is the current date. I'm getting an incorrect path format error on the path tho.

```
$nowDate=$(date)
New-Item -ItemType file "$HOME/creation_$nowDate.txt"
```

As I have just started with Powershell I really don't know what's the issue here...

Comment: PoSh can't tell that the `.txt` is part of the file name. it thinks you are talking about `$nowDate.txt` [an object with a property], not `($nowDate).txt` ... [*grin*]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However `New-Item -ItemType file "$HOME/creation_($nowDate).txt" ` is still outputing the same error.

Comment: I'd always use the international, sortable format `ni ("creation_{0:yyyyMMdd}.txt" -f (get-date))`

Comment: @AdrianDanlos - arg! [*blush*] i didn't notice that you have not defined a date format. you seem to be using a datetime object - and that won't work in the string like that. take a look at what LotPings posted. that looks like it solves your glitch.

Comment: `"$nowDate"` could contain characters  not allowed in filesystem names like `/` or `:`. Use something like `$($nowDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use just `$date` in your `nowDate` the path is incorrect because is includes spaces (folder name can't be with spaces) and is totally not the format you want.

Just change the `nowDate` to get the correct date format and it will work:

```
$nowDate = Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy
New-Item -ItemType file "$HOME/creation_$nowDate.txt"
# Result:
Folder Properties...        Name
                            ----
                            creation_02062019.txt
```